# Get full screen resolution

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7

I am trying to have full screen resolution of Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS in Virtual Box 4.3.12. My host Os is Windows 7.

I am following this steps:

> Open up a terminal and run this command to open up additional drivers:
>
> ```
> sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
> ```
>
> Click on Using x86 visualization solution If you wanted to Install
>   this in terminal you would need to run this command.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
> ```

But I'm unable to get full screen resolution.

Comment: Have you installed the extension pack and guest additions?

Comment: You should also upgrade your VirtualBox. Version 4.3.12 is pretty old and some bugfixes may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got lost some where. Boot the VM and from Devices Menu choose "Install Guest Additions". This will mount the ISO as a CD in the VM. Next Run this in terminal:

```
sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Then continue to follow on screen Instructions. Reboot the VM when done.